# Brakes QHD-6 Tork - how to fit new pads

Tags: mountain-bike, brakes

I have a Claud Butler MTB which is fitted with QHD-6 Tork hydraulic brakes.
Whilst these have worked really well for a number of years, recently the rear brakes stuck on whilst I was out.

I have now bought new pads to replace and hopefully solve the problem but I don't know how to take out the the old pads and replace them. Any help please.

Comment: Would you be able to add a photo of the brake calliper? They're not a particularly common brake to find on google, though they are likely to be similar to models people have worked on before so a photo would help

Comment: If the brakes are stuck you likely need to do more than replace the pads. The pistons are probably stuck in the caliper due to dirt build up or corrosion. Park Tool has a [good video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQXFFgRButo) on cleaning pistons and unsticking them.